# Finding the murderer

Tags: logical-deduction, mystery, letters

There are six suspects **"Siva", "Durga", "Ekagra", "Naman", "Aniket" and "Manish"**.
**Amartya** has written the murderer name in secretly in his diary in a mysterious way as **"DVVPQ"**.
Police were unable to solve the mystery so they called **Dipjyoti**.
After a minute, Dipjyoti was able to decipher the cipher and ask the police to capture the murderer.
Who is the murderer?

Just have no clue!(Question from technothlon mock)

Comment: Is this taken from the same source as your previous puzzle? If so, you need to cite it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the murderer is

> Durga

because

> the cypher is obtained after a ROT(n-1)² with n the letter's position in the name 
>  *d* ROT (1-1)² = *d* ROT 0 = *d* 
>  *u* ROT (2-1)² is *u* ROT 1 = *v* 
>  *r* ROT(3-1)² is *r* ROT 4 = *v* 
>  *g* ROT (4-1)² is *g* ROT 9 = *p* 
>  *a* ROT (5-1)² is *a* ROT 16 = *q*